# How to remove UIParallaxDimmingView in pop UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` **vc1** which is pushed after `UIViewController` **vc2**. 
Both **vc1** and **vc2** are with transparent background.

Problem:
When I try to pop **vc2** with interactive pop gesture (pan from edge), in my view stack appears mysterious `UIParallaxDimmingView` which darkens my stack (under transparent view controllers there is a background image). 
As soon as I release finger, cancel or finish transition it becomes clear/transparent again.

How can i disable/remove `UIParallaxDimmingView` or set it transparent?

Answer (score 0):

If it is pushing a VC(still animating) when you try to pop VC with interactive pop gesture(pan from edge), the app may be frozen. This can help you :

```
/ set gesture no when pushViewController /
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    }

    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
}

/ set gesture yes when showViewController /
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController )navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController )viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
        navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
    }

    / if rootViewController, set delegate nil /
    if (navigationController.viewControllers.count == 1) {
        navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
        navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;
    }
}
```